# How should I test that multiple functions were called in a loop?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, mocking

How can I make sure that all handlers were called in a loop? The best I came up with is to mock `fake_handler` function and check that this function was called a certain number of times, but I think there might be a better solution.

```
class MessageHandler:
    def __init__(self, handlers=None):
        self.handlers = handlers or []

    def handle(self, event, body):
        for handler in self.handlers:
            handler(event, body)
```

Tests:

```
def fake_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    pass


class TestMessageHandler(TestCase):
    @patch('tests.test_handlers.fake_handler')
    def test_handle(self, fake_handler_mock):
        messages = MessageHandler([fake_handler_mock, fake_handler_mock])
        messages.handle(None, None)
        self.assertEqual(fake_handler_mock.call_count, 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of issues in your test, in summary you should not be patching and you are testing too little. Let me tackle them one by one.

### Do not patch

Really, it is a huge opportunity to make mistakes or get caught in some of the many caveats it has. Almost every tutorial out there starts by using patching in order to test code that is hard to test. But your code is testable and you do not need it, this will work just as well:

```
def test_handle(self):
    handler = mock.Mock(name='handler')
    messages = MessageHandler([handler, handler])
    messages.handle(None, None)
    self.assertEqual(handler.call_count, 2)
```

### Check the arguments passed in calls to mocks

Your test checks that the handler was called twice but not the arguments passed. You'd rather check that the correct arguments were passed.

```
def test_handle(self):
    handler = mock.Mock(name='handler')
    messages = MessageHandler([handler, handler])
    messages.handle(None, None)
    self.assertEqual(
        handler.mock_calls,
        [mock.call(None, None), mock.call(None, None)]
    )
```

### Actually check the arguments

We are now checking that `None` is passed to the handlers but both the event and the body are `None` and anything else could be `None` too so we don't really know whether the code is making the right call. It is better if we use different, unique values for each argument.

```
def test_handle(self):
    handler = mock.Mock(name='handler')
    messages = MessageHandler([handler, handler])
    messages.handle(mock.sentinel.event, mock.sentinel.body)
    self.assertEqual(
        handler.mock_calls,
        [mock.call(mock.sentinel.event, mock.sentinel.body),
         mock.call(mock.sentinel.event, mock.sentinel.body)]
    )
```

### Test with different handlers

Having the same handler twice is a corner case. Even if you might want to keep this test (or change it; do you really want to allow duplicated handlers?), you really want to test the general case where the handlers are different.

```
def test_handle(self):
    handler1 = mock.Mock(name='handler1')
    handler2 = mock.Mock(name='handler2')
    messages = MessageHandler([handler1, handler2])
    messages.handle(mock.sentinel.event, mock.sentinel.body)
    handler1.assert_called_once_with(
        mock.sentinel.event, mock.sentinel.body
    )
    handler2.assert_called_once_with(
        mock.sentinel.event, mock.sentinel.body
    )
```

### Check that the handlers are called in order

If you want to assert that the calls are made in order, the above test is not enough. It will still pass if you change the order of the assertions. The only way I know to check the order in which different mocks are called is by making them attributes of the same parent mock. This doesn't make me happy at all because the test becomes concerned by an object unrelated to the behaviour I want to test but it seems to be the only way.

```
def test_handle(self):
    handlers_parent = mock.Mock(name='handlers_parent')
    handler1 = handlers_parent.handler1
    handler2 = handlers_parent.handler2
    messages = MessageHandler([handler1, handler2])
    messages.handle(mock.sentinel.event, mock.sentinel.body)
    self.assertEqual(
        handlers_parent.mock_calls,
        [mock.call.handler1(mock.sentinel.event, mock.sentinel.body),
         mock.call.handler2(mock.sentinel.event, mock.sentinel.body)]
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! You clarified a lot of things for me! The order of call is not so important for me and I will stick with "different handlers" test but thank you for the snippet, I definitely will use it in the future.